# i have two array of objects, i want to update the one which have same messageId and keep the unique one in one array in react javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

/*here its my first array which contains two objects. what i want is i want to compare two arrays of object and check if any msg have the same id, if any msg have the same id  i want update the same id msg from the second array and keep the non same msg in an array */

```
   const messageListState = [
      {
    "profileId": "",
    "receiverId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
    "messageId": "e2397e7e-9509-46ae-b53e-4af8008bdca6",
    "message": "Thank you for connecting to the bykea.",
    "msgType": "text",
    "viewObject": "",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEdited": false,
    "replyMsgId": "",
    "msgDate": 1645696234953,
    "sentDate": 1645696234953,
    "caption": "",
    "thumbnail": "",
    "customData": "",
    "chatId": "235308",
    "departmentid": "37",
    "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
    "viewId": "0",
    "viewDet": null,
    "viewOptionId": null,
    "originalFileName": "",
    "msgHeading": "",
    "msgURL": "",
    "dType": "",
    "departmentName_u": "",
    "dImage": "",
    "audioLength": "",
    "buttonDet": null,
    "tempProfileId": null,
    "campaignId": "",
    "msgExpTime": 0
    },
    {
    "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
    "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "0A3F7E50-60B5-466F-AA2E-33BA32B26A2B",
    "message": "You are now chatting with Azaan Khan",
    "msgType": "text",
    "viewObject": "",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEdited": false,
    "replyMsgId": "0",
    "msgDate": 1645696247563,
    "sentDate": 1645696247563,
    "caption": "",
    "thumbnail": "",
    "customData": "",
    "chatId": "235308",
    "departmentid": "37",
    "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
    "viewId": "0",
    "viewDet": null,
    "viewOptionId": null,
    "originalFileName": "",
    "msgHeading": "",
    "msgURL": "",
    "dType": "",
    "departmentName_u": "",
    "dImage": "",
    "audioLength": "",
    "buttonDet": null,
    "tempProfileId": null,
    "campaignId": "",
    "msgExpTime": 0
    }]
```

/*here is my function*/

```
   const updateById = (obj) => {
   return  obj.map((msg)=>{
   return messageListState.map((message) => 
   {return message?.messageId === msg.messageId ? msg : message})
   })
  }
```

/*here i m calling the function with my second array as a parameter*/

```
  const newMsg = updateById(
    [ {
    "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
    "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "0A3F7E50-60B5-466F-AA2E-33BA32B26A2B",
    "message": "iloveu",
    "msgType": "text",
    "viewObject": "",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEdited": true,
    "replyMsgId": "0",
    "msgDate": 1645696247563,
    "sentDate": 1645696247563,
    "caption": "",
    "thumbnail": "",
    "customData": "",
    "chatId": "235308",
    "departmentid": "37",
    "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
    "viewId": "0",
    "viewDet": null,
    "viewOptionId": null,
    "originalFileName": "",
    "msgHeading": "",
    "msgURL": "",
    "dType": "",
    "departmentName_u": "",
    "dImage": "",
    "audioLength": "",
    "buttonDet": null,
    "tempProfileId": null,
    "campaignId": "",
    "msgExpTime": 0
    },
   {
  "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
  "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
  "messageId": "1",
  "message": "mohti",
  "msgType": "text",
  "viewObject": "",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isEdited": false,
  "replyMsgId": "0",
  "msgDate": 1645696247563,
  "sentDate": 1645696247563,
  "caption": "",
  "thumbnail": "",
  "customData": "",
  "chatId": "235308",
  "departmentid": "37",
  "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
  "viewId": "0",
  "viewDet": null,
  "viewOptionId": null,
  "originalFileName": "",
  "msgHeading": "",
  "msgURL": "",
  "dType": "",
  "departmentName_u": "",
  "dImage": "",
  "audioLength": "",
  "buttonDet": null,
  "tempProfileId": null,
  "campaignId": "",
  "msgExpTime": 0
     }
    ]
   )
   console.log(newMsg)
```

/*the result i want is like this:*/

```
newMsg = [
      {
    "profileId": "",
    "receiverId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
    "messageId": "e2397e7e-9509-46ae-b53e-4af8008bdca6",
    "message": "Thank you for connecting to the bykea.",
    "msgType": "text",
    "viewObject": "",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEdited": false,
    "replyMsgId": "",
    "msgDate": 1645696234953,
    "sentDate": 1645696234953,
    "caption": "",
    "thumbnail": "",
    "customData": "",
    "chatId": "235308",
    "departmentid": "37",
    "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
    "viewId": "0",
    "viewDet": null,
    "viewOptionId": null,
    "originalFileName": "",
    "msgHeading": "",
    "msgURL": "",
    "dType": "",
    "departmentName_u": "",
    "dImage": "",
    "audioLength": "",
    "buttonDet": null,
    "tempProfileId": null,
    "campaignId": "",
    "msgExpTime": 0
    },
{
    "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
    "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
    "messageId": "0A3F7E50-60B5-466F-AA2E-33BA32B26A2B",
    "message": "iloveu",
    "msgType": "text",
    "viewObject": "",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isEdited": true,
    "replyMsgId": "0",
    "msgDate": 1645696247563,
    "sentDate": 1645696247563,
    "caption": "",
    "thumbnail": "",
    "customData": "",
    "chatId": "235308",
    "departmentid": "37",
    "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
    "viewId": "0",
    "viewDet": null,
    "viewOptionId": null,
    "originalFileName": "",
    "msgHeading": "",
    "msgURL": "",
    "dType": "",
    "departmentName_u": "",
    "dImage": "",
    "audioLength": "",
    "buttonDet": null,
    "tempProfileId": null,
    "campaignId": "",
    "msgExpTime": 0
    },
   {
  "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
  "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
  "messageId": "1",
  "message": "mohti",
  "msgType": "text",
  "viewObject": "",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isEdited": false,
  "replyMsgId": "0",
  "msgDate": 1645696247563,
  "sentDate": 1645696247563,
  "caption": "",
  "thumbnail": "",
  "customData": "",
  "chatId": "235308",
  "departmentid": "37",
  "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
  "viewId": "0",
  "viewDet": null,
  "viewOptionId": null,
  "originalFileName": "",
  "msgHeading": "",
  "msgURL": "",
  "dType": "",
  "departmentName_u": "",
  "dImage": "",
  "audioLength": "",
  "buttonDet": null,
  "tempProfileId": null,
  "campaignId": "",
  "msgExpTime": 0
     }
]
```

Comment: Kindly edit your question and clear the details as you said you have 2 arrays of objects and if they have same messageID then you want to update the one (which one array). And the output you have attached have only unique messageId.

Comment: Reference nhe toot raha, see methods of cloning array, you must have to clone the array after editing otherwise react state variable doesn’t think it has changed and do not rerender the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const messageListState = [
{
   "profileId": "",
"receiverId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
"messageId": "e2397e7e-9509-46ae-b53e-4af8008bdca6",
"message": "Thank you for connecting to the bykea.",
"msgType": "text",
"viewObject": "",
"isDeleted": false,
"isEdited": false,
"replyMsgId": "",
"msgDate": 1645696234953,
"sentDate": 1645696234953,
"caption": "",
"thumbnail": "",
"customData": "",
"chatId": "235308",
"departmentid": "37",
"departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
"viewId": "0",
"viewDet": null,
"viewOptionId": null,
"originalFileName": "",
"msgHeading": "",
"msgURL": "",
"dType": "",
"departmentName_u": "",
"dImage": "",
"audioLength": "",
"buttonDet": null,
"tempProfileId": null,
"campaignId": "",
"msgExpTime": 0
},
{
"profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
"receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
"messageId": "0A3F7E50-60B5-466F-AA2E-33BA32B26A2B",
"message": "You are now chatting with Azaan Khan",
"msgType": "text",
"viewObject": "",
"isDeleted": false,
"isEdited": false,
"replyMsgId": "0",
"msgDate": 1645696247563,
"sentDate": 1645696247563,
"caption": "",
"thumbnail": "",
"customData": "",
"chatId": "235308",
"departmentid": "37",
"departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
"viewId": "0",
"viewDet": null,
"viewOptionId": null,
"originalFileName": "",
"msgHeading": "",
"msgURL": "",
"dType": "",
"departmentName_u": "",
"dImage": "",
"audioLength": "",
"buttonDet": null,
"tempProfileId": null,
"campaignId": "",
"msgExpTime": 0
}];
const state2= [ {
  "profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
  "receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
  "messageId": "0A3F7E50-60B5-466F-AA2E-33BA32B26A2B",
  "message": "iloveu",
  "msgType": "text",
  "viewObject": "",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "isEdited": true,
  "replyMsgId": "0",
  "msgDate": 1645696247563,
  "sentDate": 1645696247563,
  "caption": "",
  "thumbnail": "",
  "customData": "",
  "chatId": "235308",
  "departmentid": "37",
  "departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
  "viewId": "0",
  "viewDet": null,
  "viewOptionId": null,
  "originalFileName": "",
  "msgHeading": "",
  "msgURL": "",
  "dType": "",
  "departmentName_u": "",
  "dImage": "",
  "audioLength": "",
  "buttonDet": null,
  "tempProfileId": null,
  "campaignId": "",
  "msgExpTime": 0
  },
{
"profileId": "1072e315-a372-4f3f-81c0-344979980add",
"receiverId": "agent001@gmail.com",
"messageId": "1",
"message": "mohti",
"msgType": "text",
"viewObject": "",
"isDeleted": false,
"isEdited": false,
"replyMsgId": "0",
"msgDate": 1645696247563,
"sentDate": 1645696247563,
"caption": "",
"thumbnail": "",
"customData": "",
"chatId": "235308",
"departmentid": "37",
"departmentName": "Foreign Remittance",
"viewId": "0",
"viewDet": null,
"viewOptionId": null,
"originalFileName": "",
"msgHeading": "",
"msgURL": "",
"dType": "",
"departmentName_u": "",
"dImage": "",
"audioLength": "",
"buttonDet": null,
"tempProfileId": null,
"campaignId": "",
"msgExpTime": 0
  }
  ]
const compareArr=(arr1,arr2)=>{
  let items1=arr1.map((item)=>{
    let i=arr2.findIndex((it)=>it.messageId===item.messageId);
    if(i!=-1){
      item.message=arr2[i].message;
    }
    return item;
  });
  let items2=arr2.filter((i)=>!items1.find((it)=>it.messageId===i.messageId));
  return [...items1,...items2];
}

console.log(compareArr(messageListState,state2));
```

Comment: @Azaan Khan is your problem solved?